# How to stop my Acer Aspire 8730 laptop from moving letters and words around while I'm typing?

Tags: touchpad

As I type, the letters move to different sentences, breaking those sentences and destroying the sentence I'm typing.  This is happening in Word, Facebook and E-mails.  I can't finish a sentence without it happening at least twice!  some have mentioned to disable the Touchpad, but in Windows 7, there doesn't seem to be a way to do it with this Acer laptop!

Comment: Most touchpad software has a option to detect accidental detection, I would very much expect Asus touchpad software to do this

Answer (score 4):

On acer laptop you will have to press FN key and the key mentioning mouse sign to disable/enable mouse pad. Search the mousepad sign on Keys from F1 to F10 keys.

Comment: On Acer laptops it's usually Fn+F7

Answer (score 1):

Is there an option to disable the touchpad in the BIOS -- typically accessed by pressing <kbd>del</kbd>, <kbd>f8</kbd>, or <kbd>f12</kbd> during bootup?

Beyond that look for newer touchpad drivers from the manufacturer's website, they may offer something like what Synaptic does:

http://www.synaptics.com/support/drivers

> PalmCheck
>
> The PalmCheck™ feature guards against unintentional cursor movement and tapping caused by accidental contact of the palm or hand with the TouchPad. PalmCheck allows the TouchPad to recognize when a user’s palm is resting on it or brushing its surface while typing. This helps prevent unwanted pointer movement or clicks.

However, this will only work if your touchpad is a Synaptic model.

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of ways to disable your touchpad as you type just find the one that suits you best.

http://lifehacker.com/5590583/touchpadpal-decreases-errors-by-disabling-the-touchpad-while-you-type

http://lifehacker.com/5480260/disable-your-touchpad-when-youre-typing-with-autohotkey

http://lifehacker.com/5412986/touchfreeze-disables-your-touchpad-as-soon-as-you-start-typing

Answer (score 0):

Try [TouchFreeze](https://code.google.com/p/touchfreeze/) utility: it block all mouse and touchpad clicks within short interval after every key press:
https://code.google.com/p/touchfreeze/